# Document error xml

Tags: java, xml, archivo, class, documentbuilder

Buenas estoy con problemas para crear el objeto doc en el siguiente codigo, quiero guardar en el objeto de tipo Documento, pero al final me da error que no se como solucionar.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class Xml {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        factory.setValidating(true);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        File file = new File("C:\\users\\enriq\\desktop\\prueba1.xml");
        Document doc = builder.parse(file);

    }
```

}

Comment: En tu código, estás importando javax.swing.text.Document, que es la interfaz de documentos de texto para aplicaciones Swing, en lugar de org.w3c.dom.Document, que es la interfaz que se utiliza comúnmente para representar documentos XML en Java.